# java dynamically determine currently executing class

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, lambda

I'm trying to write a Serializable lambda which can call a method within the object instance which runs it.

I'm going to be passing this lambda to the object instance which is will run it, immediately after instantiating it, but because I want to serialize these objects containing the lambdas, I need a way of dynamically determining a reference to the object instance.

here is what I'd like to do if the currentClass() method existed.

```
Runnable r = (Runnable & Serializable)() -> {
  try { 
    // currentClass() doesn't exist
    Class curClass = Thread.currentThread().currentClass();
    Method setCol = curClass.getMethod("setColor", Class.forName("Color"));
    setCol.invoke(curClass, Color.BLACK);

  } catch (NoSuchMethodException e | ClassNotFoundException e
      | IllegalAccessException e | IllegalArgumentException e 
      | InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}

MySquare sq = new MySquare();
sq.setRunnable(r);

sq.runRunnable(); // calls r.run()
```

To clarify, I'd like to serialize `sq`.
Then when I read recreate `sq` from the .ser file, I'd like to be able to execute `sq.runRunnable()`

Comment: You should probably write a proper object for this instead of trying to use a lambda expression. Serializing lambdas is a tricky business in the first place. (edit: also see http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I agree this looks like an XY Problem.  Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve, not how you think it should be implemented.

Comment: Sorry, this was an XY problem, I've found a solution to the actual problem, which is

Serializing a lambda which can make method calls on the object instance containing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorted it by changing the lambda from a `Runnable` to a `Consumer<MySquare>`

e.g. `Consumer<MySquare> r = (sq) -> {sq.setColor(Color.BLACK)}`

and changing the `runRunnable()` method to now execute `r.accept(this)`